# Ultimate get current page's slug function

Tags: slug

Am I missing something or is there really still no built in WP function to return the current page slug on whatever page you are currently on?

I understand there isn't, so I'm wondering if anyone out there has a bullet proof function to do this ?

The problem is that most solutions I find don't work 100% of the time, such as these scenarios:

- They only work in the post loop
- or only outside of the loop
- cant obtain the correct value, for example from an archive page where code often has a tendency to start returning slugs of the posts themselves
- they have problems when pagination appears in the url (/news/page/2/)

To give an example of why I want such a function right now; I have code I need to call from the functions.php file (a hook) and that needs to only fire on a specific page, which is the posts listing (archive) page.   So the url of that page is defined by the "page" that was created and then setup as the archive listing page via the Settings/Reading option.

So if my domain and news listing page was [www.test.com/news/](http://www.test.com/news/) the result I'd want from this function is "news".

So before I re-invent the wheel with some monster function to handle all these situations, can someone confirm if anything does already exist that would help ?

Comment: Are you asking for how to do this or are you asking for a recommendation? Because the latter is off-topic, whereas the former is on topic. Note that you may be confusing getting the slug of the main post the URL fetched, vs the slug of the current post ( which changes everytime `the_post` is called ). And that archives do not have a post ID or post slug because they aren't singular ( but pages with page templates that are masquerading as archives do, and this is a very important distinction ). Also what are you trying to do that requires this?

Comment: The former.   To clarify,  by slug of the page I am referring to the permalink document name.   I want such a function because it simply would be incredibly useful.  Countless time's I've wanted it in the past and usually had to use a more complex piece of code to deduct what page the user is on.    The specific case of why I want it this time I'm going to write now in the original question text.

Comment: usually this is just the slug of the queried object on the main query, which would work universally, and there are dedicated functions in WP for grabbing that. The only case this wouldn't work is when you use the `query_posts` function, but you should never use that function ( use `WP_Query`, `get_posts` or the `pre_get_posts` filter instead ). Note that some URLs do not have a slug, e.g. the homepage, RSS feeds, REST API endpoints, WP Admin, XMLRPC, certain types of archives such as date/month archives and so on. Some pages aren't actually pages but rewrite rules

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a single permalink document name. It varies depending on what is being queried. Taxonomy terms use the slug of the term, pages and posts uses the slug of the posts. Post type archives sometimes use the post type name, but they might use something else entirely depending on how it's registered. Not to mention that date archives and search results don't have a definitive slug, and the blog may use the slug of another page, or it may be the homepage.

The problem is the premise of your question is incorrect. You mentioned that you have something that "only fire on a specific page, which is the posts listing (archive) page". But if you want to know if you're on that page, checking if the slug is 'news' is not the correct way to do this, since you'd be hardcoding a value that could change, and if your "ultimate" function existed how would you tell the difference between a blog page named "news" and a category named "news"? The proper approach for this sort of thing is to use the appropriate documented [conditional tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/). In your case that's [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/).

Comment: Hi @Jacob yes I take your point that the permalink of the page *could* change.   However I do work on either single user (except me) sites and/or sites where all users are with limited control and the only person that can change something like this is me so I still stand by this being a valid approach in some use cases.  Besides, lots of the example conditionals WP document themselves are doing exactly what you are saying not to do.  Ie is_single(), is_page() work on the premise that you will supply them a page ID or permalink name.